# It's possible to use same domain (a custom system) but different frameworks in specific url?

Tags: node.js, angular, apache, session, authentication

I do not know if am I being clear, but what I want to do is:

**I have a system:** www.example.com

This system have many pages/endpoints, all creating with outdated Angular (frontend) + outdated Lumen (api/backend).

Now I need to create a new page/endpoint, and I want to use Node.js + Vue.js, but keeping the same database and the actual login session/cookies. It's possible?

**Example:**

- http://www.example.com/auth/login -> Angular + Lumen
- http://www.example.com/reports -> Angular + Lumen
- http://www.example.com/dashboard -> Node + Vue

If you need more information, ask me please.

Comment: Add proxy server in the front like nginx based on route change the proxy server, use a common store to share the session.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, you have to use nginx as reverse-proxy, start your applications on differents ports and then configure a nginx virtualhosts for each application on different locations like this example where your lumen app is running on port 6001 and the node+vue on 6002.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
location /dashboard/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6002/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

There are countless tutorials on how to configure a nginx server.

The same concept applies to apache too.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for the answer.